# how to check: if array includes specific text properly?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, indexof

I am struggling with doing an array search that includes a piece of text that must include back slashes in it. I have tried `includes('');` negating `includes('');` and also trying similar using `indexOf('')`.

I have a simple array, with at maximum four values; typically it has two, here is how it typically looks:

```
{tks: Array(2)}
tks: Array(2)
0: "https://mycoolwebsite.net/arcgis/rest/services"
1: "https://mycoolwebsite.com/arcgis/rest/services"
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
```

Here are the simple checks I'm trying to do: My second check with `*includes*` `'wdt'` text seems to be working so ***I assume it's something with the backslashes. Anyway I can handle this?*** I'm perplexed why my `if` and `else` both get hit with the first check below using back slashes... I added the negating on the `else` to double check.. with and without that in the `else`, `else` is always hit.

```
    // right before doing the search I am building the array, just to add more context

    for (let i = 0; i < coolObj.length; i++) {
      if (coolObj[i].url){
          tr = coolObj[i].url;
          tks.push(tr);

          console.log({tks});     
       }
     }

    console.log({tks}); // consoles as I have included above ^

    if (tks.includes('/arcgis/rest/services')) {
            
      console.log({tks});     

    } else if (!tks.includes('/arcgis/rest/services')) { 

      console.log({tks});

      console.log('does not include correct url');
      aT = '/arcgis/rest/services';
      lP = false;
      filterAt(aT);
    }
    if (tks.includes('wdt')) {
      console.log({tks});

    }else {
      console.log({tks});
      wT = 'wdt';
      filterWt(wT);
    }
```

Comment: You only doing a compare of the whole value,..  eg.  None of you compare have the full url with `https://...` etc in them,   IOW: none of your includes are going to return true.

Comment: Wow... then what could I do to achieve 'contains' specific text?

Comment: You will want to loop the array, and check each array item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes): *The includes() method determines whether an array includes a certain value among its entries, returning true or false as appropriate.*

You have to test the strings using `String.prototype.includes` within the array elements thus:

```js
const arr = ["https://mycoolwebsite.net/arcgis/rest/services", "https://mycoolwebsite.com/arcgis/rest/services"];

arr.forEach(el => {
  if (el.includes('/arcgis/rest/services')) {
    console.log(el, ': includes url');
  }
  else {
    console.log('does not include correct url');
  }
  if (el.includes('wdt')) {
    console.log(el, ': includes wdt');
  } else {
    console.log('does not include correct wdt');

  }

});
```